# Traversing a sibling node in JSOUP based on a search text

Tags: java, jsoup

Consider the below HTML from a URL. I need to first perform a search on the text "Student 1" and pick the corresponding school which in this case is 'MIT School'. How do I do this in JSOUP ?

```
<table>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td valign="top"> 
   <div style="border-width:1px;border-color:#cccccc;border-style:solid;"> 
    <table bordercolor="#483D8B"> 
     <tbody>
      <tr> 
       <th colspan="2" bgcolor="#483D8B" height="25"><font face="Verdana" size="2" color="white">MIT School</font></th> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
       <td width="120" height="15"><font face="Arial" size="2" color="black"> <b>Student 1</b> </font></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So far I have only been able to perform a successful search for the text.

```
System.out.println("This is :"+Jsoup.parse(url, timeout)
                        .select("b:containsOwn(Student 1");
```

The output I get is

```
<b>This is :Student 1</b>
```

I could not find many examples online for JSOUP. Any help with this one?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct `HTML`? Where does the `b` tag in your `select` comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider that each student has a dedicated table. Then, you could try the following:

```
    Element sibling = doc.select("b:containsOwn(Student 1)")
            .first().parent().parent().parent().firstElementSibling();
    System.out.println(sibling.select("th").text());
```

Note that, in this case we take into consideration only the first result. You have to iterate all b elements that contains 'Student 1' in order to take all the data points you want.